# MVVM Light RelayCommandin reverse?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Is it possible to utilise `RelayCommand` as a dependency property on a custom `UserControl`?

I need to action my View from my ViewModel and don't like the ideas I've found so far that use a bool for signalling or use the Messenger and have the UserControl or Code behind listen for a Message.

It would seem logical to use `ICommand` in reverse. My `UserControl` can expose a dependency property of type `RelayCommand` and then once bound to a `RelayCommand` property on my ViewModel the ViewModel can call `CanExecute()` and `Execute()` as required without having knowledge of the actual View.

Is this possible? I can't find any examples that do it this way?

Cheers

Dave

Comment: Possible or not, it might be breaking the pattern by adding a dependency on the View in the ViewModel.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how the VM would be dependent on the View any more than if using RelayCommand the other way around? My VM doesn't need to understand who the View is and it could easily be a test module that was providing the RelayCommand for the VM to fire when required? Does that make sense?